# How to execute a program with command line arguments on EC2 remotely (java program)?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, jsch

I want to start a EC2 instance from java code and execute python code on that EC2 instance.

1. Create a custom AMI with python console application
2. launch EC2 instance using AMI from java application
3. launch multiple instances of python program with different command line arguments from java code.

I have done some analysis where I can create AMI with python code and launch EC2 instance, but I am looking for a way to launch multiple instances of python program with command line arguments.

[image]

Basically I want to build a scalable system which will start EC2 instance and launch multiple python processes as per requirement and will remove  EC2 instance as work is done.

**UPDATE:** Although accepted answer is correct there is another way to execute scripts remotely using ssh tunneling using JSCH java library , here is the 
[Gist](https://gist.github.com/nakshay/8d3eb1337c1217095f9eea0e4b54a3a5) for sample code

This can be used for communication with non AWS machine with SSH service on.

Comment: May I ask how do you start your python program? Is it running over Django or you are using plain python scripts?

Comment: Its plain script, I am looking for a way to start it from java server which will is going to start AMI.

Comment: AWS has SDK https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use AWS Systems Manager to invoke shell commands on your remote EC2 instance.

1. Create a document in AWS SSM which invokes the shell commands.
2. Create an EC2 role which allows SSM to run commands on EC2 instance on your behalf.
3. Attach that role to that instance and wait for that instance to come under `Managed Instance` inside SSM.
4. Run that SSM document on that instance from Java.

Comment: This need to be executed on EC2 instance and from java program which is running on different server. so this approach wont work

Comment: is this accessible using java API

Comment: I got the fair idea about SSM documents, but having hard time finding the java sdk samples/examples, can you provide any?

Comment: Well, you can look here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/simplesystemsmanagement/AWSSimpleSystemsManagement.html#sendCommand-com.amazonaws.services.simplesystemsmanagement.model.SendCommandRequest- for starters.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203151/discussion-between-akshay-naik-and-rahul-sharma).